# How to check how much disk space Core Data is using?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I am writing a core data app that uses an sqlite-type persistent store and I know the tables and the data are stored somewhere on the device.

Is it possible to check how much memory Core Data is using to store objects? Maybe by checking the size of the sqlite db files?

If possible, how? I could really use your ideas

Comment: Navigate into your app's directory, loop through all files until you find the sqlite extension. Read the file size.

Comment: How do you check the size of a file programmatically? Could you add a little code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the xcode you are using

**In `ios8`**

It stored somewhere

> / Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/(numbers and
>   letters)/data/Containers/Data/Application/(numbers and
>   letters)/Documents/

(numbers and letters) stands for a folder that would be unique to your app/computer, but would look like this: 779AE2245-F8W2-57A9-8C6D-98643B1CF01A

You can do by writing below method into`appDelegate.m,`

method, and NSLogging the return path, like this:

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);

    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
 }
```

It will give you `document` directory url on simulator.Than go to finder `Cmd+Shift+G` and type this address here you can navigate to `sqlite` files which used by core data to store the data of your app

**for Xcode 3 ,Xcode 4 and for Xcpde 5 it stores in**

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[SDK
>   version]/Applications/[App GUID]/Documents

**EDIT** You can use following code for check the size of your `sqlite db` of core data.I think it will work in all cases but i am not sure and also i do not verified its acuuracy.But i think it is one way to give top level details of checking the `coredata` db size programmatically

```
-(NSUInteger)calculate{

    //Check where you are making the sqlite
    NSURL *url = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPersistentStoreName"];
    NSUInteger sizeOfData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] length];
    NSLog(@"sizeOfDAta in bytes %lu",(unsigned long)sizeOfData);

    return sizeOfData; 
}
```

Comment: I meant programmatically check the size. Do you know if this is possible? Or any other way to know estimate how much data is being stored?

Comment: i have eidted my answer have a look.I have tested this on simulator and it is working fine

Comment: That will be incorrect in most cases. The size of the SQLite file does not include the size of the journal files, which can be much bigger than the primary SQLite file.