# How to get the size of Documents & data present in application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am adding some data in my application like class room information(class name, number of students in that class and classroom images) using core data. After addition of many record of class information I want to know how much document data size(in KB or MB) present in my app. So is it possible to get the size of documents & data as we can see from phone setting storage? If possible then how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check how much disk space Core Data is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023205/how-to-check-how-much-disk-space-core-data-is-using)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to determine the file properties

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:<File Path> error:&error];

NSNumber *fileSize = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
double tempSize = (double)([fileSize unsignedLongLongValue]/(1000.0*1000.0));
```

This will give you file size in MB